# MongoDB: Is finding all entities with list of ids performance?

Tags: mongodb, database

In MongoDB, I know that joining two "table" are not performance. But as on MongoDB website, there is a method that: reference all ids in one document. For example:

```
Book {
 title
 content
 author [ author_id1, author_id2, author_id3]
}
```

So my question is : as above design, when I get a book, I have list of author ids, then I can query on Author Collections to get all authors. In MongoDB, is this behavior performance ? Because I get all entities by using its index.

Reversing, I have Author Collection:

```
Author {
 name
 year
 first_written_book_id
}
```

So, I use `first_written_book_id` for querying to get book detail. Does this action gains performance as on RDBMS ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query `author` collection and it can be very efficient, but you have to have index on your `name` field. If you use `_id` to access authors, then you don't need anything else.

Your queries might look like this:

```
db.authors.find({_id: {$in: [ author_id1, author_id2, author_id3]}})
db.authors.find({name: {$in: [ author_id1, author_id2, author_id3]}})
```

See more info [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/). `$in` operator is able to use existing indexes to speed up query execution.